# Helm configmap error Error: UPGRADE FAILED: ConfigMap "my-service.v130" is invalid: data: Too long: must have at most 1048576 characters

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm getting this error `Error: UPGRADE FAILED: ConfigMap "my-service.v130" is invalid: data: Too long: must have at most 1048576 characters` when running the command:

```
$ KUBECONFIG=/Users/tomcaflisch/.kube/config.dev helm upgrade --wait --recreate-pods --install my-service --version v0.1.0-gedc3d28-dirty  -f ./values.yaml  -f ./secrets.yaml  -f ./vars/dev/db.yaml  -f ./vars/dev/epic.yaml  -f ./vars/dev/ingress.yaml  -f ./vars/dev/services.yaml  -f ./vars/dev/tkn.yaml --set image.tag=v0.1.0-gedc3d28-dirty .
```

I can't image my generated configmap is even close to that limit. How can i go about debugging this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a known problem, you can find several issues regarding it - [that one](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/1996), for an example.

Configmap objects on Kubernetes have 1Mb size limit and unfortunately (or maybe fortunately) you cannot change it.

Anyway, that is a bad idea to increase the limit, because K8s store Configmaps in Etcd, which don't like large objects.

Helm uses configmap of release for store many things, include chart files and it can be your problem.

Try to add all files (like `.git` directory) in chart dir (except chart files itself) to `.helmignore` file and push release another one time.

Comment: I had to add a dir such as my `coverage/` dir to `.helmignore` as it was pushing my size over the limit.

Comment: Like Catfish says, check also a (new) folder with something large there, this might be confusing helm. In my case, I added a folder with some Images (for documentation purposes), and the problem started, only after adding to .helmignore everything got back to normal.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the root cause was very unexpected: the chart folder contained the xxxx.tgz file (the archive file left there by mistake) and until it was deleted, I got this error all the time. The error message isn't even close to the real root cause. It was definitely larger than the 1Mb limitation on the configs.

Comment: Exactly the same here so I added `my-chart-name-*.tgz` into `.helmignore` for when I'm running some builds locally.